# nginx - create multiple cache paths

Tags: caching, nginx

I am new to nginx, so I'm not sure if this is possible.

However, I am attempting to create *short*, *long*, and *never* caches for sites to use.

I naively attempted to set these up in my *http* block:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=short:10m;
proxy_cache short;
proxy_cache_key "short:$scheme$proxy_host$uri$is_args$args";
proxy_cache_valid 2m;

proxy_cache_path /data/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=long:10m;
proxy_cache long;
proxy_cache_key "long:$scheme$proxy_host$uri$is_args$args";
proxy_cache_valid 1h;

proxy_cache_path /data/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=day:10m;
proxy_cache never;
proxy_cache_key "long:$scheme$proxy_host$uri$is_args$args";
proxy_cache_valid 1d;

proxy_cache off;
```

Upon reload this throws the following error:

> [emerg]: "proxy_cache" directive is duplicate in

How can I setup different cache paths to share among my virtual hosts?

Answer (score 5):

The `proxy_cache` directive means "*use this cache right now in this block*" so as you are using this directive multiple times nginx can't decide which cache to use and shows and error. What you must do is remove `proxy_cache` and `proxy_cache_valid` directives and use one of each at a time in location and/or server blocks.

You must know that the usage of `proxy_cache` and `proxy_cache_valid` directives is forbidden in `if` blocks so you may not get what you want this way (I'm assuming you will select a particular cache based on some test).

Therefore, an other approach is to use specific headers in upstream's reply. You can use one of the following headers to set caching time :

- `X-Accel-Expires`
- `Cache-Control`
- `Expires`

Nginx will honor these headers by default. You can tell him to ignore some of those when deciding the caching duration with `proxy_ignore_headers`.

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, it is not possible to predefine multiple proxy caches? You have to define only one or redefine them for vhost/server?

Comment: Proxy_cache_path is usable multiple times in the http block. Proxy_cache and proxy_cache_valid can be used in location blocks and server blocks but no duplication of the directives in these blocks.

Comment: Ok. I was trying to predefine a few different caches based on longevity and then toggle between them for different *locations*. However, it sounds like that is not possible. It seems the way is to just define one cache and then change the longevity (using proxy_cache_valid) for different *locations*.